# Maven archetype for liferay hook

Tags: maven, hook, liferay, maven-archetype

Liferay has not provided maven archetype for hook. But they have provided eclipse plug-in to create a hook. Does any one know how to create a maven archetype for Liferay hook?  And how should I build it to create a war file out of it?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can check it out from [LR svn repository](http://svn.liferay.com/repos/public/portal/trunk/support-maven/archetypes/liferay-hook-archetype/)

Answer (score 1):

Liferay now provides archetypes for various development projects (hooks, themes, portlets, etc.)
https://www.liferay.com/web/mika.koivisto/blog/-/blogs/12322618